# 404 component being hit when navigating to child routes

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular 6 app which includes child routes from feature modules, but the 404 route defined in the app module is being hit when I navigate to any child route.

My app routing looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from '../core/containers/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule( {
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot( routes ) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
} )
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

And my child routes look like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DevelopmentHomeComponent } from './containers/development-home/development-home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'development',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: DevelopmentHomeComponent },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    DevelopmentHomeComponent
  ],
})
export class DevelopmentModule { }
```

When I navigate to `/development`, the 404 component is rendered instead of the `DevelopmentHomeComponent`. Why is this?

I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059345/angular-child-route-and-404), but there are no solutions. The comment recommends merging all the routes into one but I don't want to take this approach.

I also looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015385/angular-2-router-wildcard-handling-with-child-routes) but again I don't want to take this approach.

I have been looking at Todd Motto's [source code for his Angular training](https://github.com/UltimateAngular/angular-fundamentals-src/tree/master/37-routing) and I can't see any difference between my code and his.

Comment: Try add a component with a `router-outlet` for your `development` path.  There are some useful notes in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration) on this.

Comment: Is this new in Angular 6? Todd is writing for Angular 4, but his code works fine without this component without a <router-outlet>.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Und3rTow, but it is still hitting the `NotFoundComponent` when navigating to `/development`